# Problems with EnterpriseServicesInteropOption, NHibernate and Win7

Tags: c#, windows, oracle

i have an application development framework 2.0, NHibernate and Oracle. Everything works well in Win Server 2003/2008 and Win XP, but I changed my SO Win XP to Win 7 and the problems started. All my transactions stopped working, only operations with EnterpriseServicesInteropOption.Full.

I don't have any ideia what config I need to do in Win 7, because with Win XP worked.

below a stretch of code, when save de object I receive an OracleException:

Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException Unable to enlist in a distributed transaction

```
TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options, EnterpriseServicesInteropOption.Full))
{                       
       // Problems here
   classDao.Save(class);

   scope.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TransactionScope` will open a distributed transaction if needed.

Distributed transactions require msdtc to be running on the server!

You can check if it is running by doing the following ([taken from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31ea46a0-ffa6-4d05-bcb5-b95bc62c5a41/error-unable-to-enlist-distributed-transaction?forum=adodotnetdataproviders))

> You need to check if msdtc service is running (by default it's
>   disabled). Open a command prompt (admin) and run: net start msdtc.
>   Next you need to configure msdtc to allow network transactions, Start
>   | Run -> comexp.msc Then dig down until you get to Distributed
>   Transaction Coordinator, right click on Local DTC and select
>   properties.  Go to security tab and enable network transactions and XA
>   transactions.

Comment: Micha, thanks for answer. I've done everything, but the problems remains. Is it possible to be something else?

Comment: idk, could be 100s of different issues ;)
Maybe just google for the error, there are lots of postings, maybe this one could be interesting although it is rather old https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1038580

Comment: most of the answers on google are about Local DTC. I've both version of oracle client installed, I'll try the suggestions in the link you that sent. Grateful for the attention =)

Comment: I solved my problem, I used Oracle client v 10.2. Reading the oracle forum, my Oracle version has a problem with MSDTC of win 7, if I wanted to continue v 10.2, i needed to send support to Oracle metalink. Was simpler change my Oracle client to v 11.2. Greateful again Micha.